# How to get one record per account?

Tags: sql

I have a query:

```
select memo_account ,flags_3,SUFFIX,date
   FROM MEMO
   left join daily on daily.ACCOUNT= memo.memo_account
   where flags_3  = 1 and suffix in (08,00)  
   and memo_number  =3333
```

which im getting the account that are in both tables.
I get the results in two rows for each account base on the suffix is 00 or 08.

How would i get it to be that i can get the account to only show once
and the suffix depending if is 00 or 08 in one row?

for example:

memo_account | suffix_00 |suffix_08 |date

I made a http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e509b/2

Comment: Just to be sure: what you want is to return the *first* occurrence of `suffix`? or *any* suffix, as long as it's only one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select memo_account, 
       max(case when SUFFIX = '00' then '00' else null end) as suff00, 
       max(case when SUFFIX = '08' then '08' else null end) as suff08, 
       date
   FROM MEMO
   left join daily on daily.ACCOUNT= memo.memo_account
   where flag_3  = 1 and suffix in (08,00)  
   and memo_number  =3333
group by memo_account, date
```

You have a date also, so you'll get some extra rows if there different dates for the same memo_account